# Invalid property name - Kivy python

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

**tuto.py**:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class CustomWidget(Widget):
    pass

class CustomWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomWidget()

customwidget = CustomWidgetApp()
customwidget.run()
```

**customwidget.kv**:

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bt-down.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

    <CustomWidget>:
        CustButton:
            text: "Random"
            pos: root.x, 200

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, root.y

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, 400
```

I run this code and I immediately get this error:

```
 ...
       7:    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
       8:
 >>    9:    <CustomWidget>:
      10:        CustButton:
      11:            text: "Random"
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like your post includes mostly code. Could you include more details? For example, what is this code supposed to be doing? What output do you desire to get? What do you already understand about the error? Is this your own code or are you copying it from somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was due to indentation in the kv file.

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class CustomWidget(Widget):
    pass


class CustomWidgetApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CustomWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CustomWidgetApp().run()
```

## customwidget.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bt-down.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

<CustomWidget>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 150
    background_color: 0.88, 0.88, 0.88, 1
    CustButton:
        text: "Random"
        pos: root.x, 200
    CustButton:
        text: "Buttom"
        pos: 200, root.y
    CustButton:
        text: "Buttom"
        pos: 200, 400
```

Answer (score 1):

The indendation is wrong. This is how it should look like:

**customwidget.kv**

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bt-down.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

<CustomWidget>:
    CustButton:
        text: "Random"
        pos: root.x, 200

    CustButton:
        text: "Buttom"
        pos: 200, root.y

    CustButton:
        text: "Buttom"
        pos: 200, 400
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the beginning of KV file. You have a rule `<CustButton@Button>:` and inside it some properties. Then there's the `<CustomWidget>:` thing. From the first look it appears to me that it's just a wrong indentation as suggested above, however let's look why the error was about `property` instead.

KV language parser checks for `on_` syntax. If that isn't present, then the indented item can be either a property or a `Widget` (or a class that inherits from it). The parser checks whether the `<CustomWidget>:` is an instance it could add as a child.

- it's not and it can't proceed

It checks if it's a property, or better said if there's some property named like `<CustomWidget>:` in the `CustButton` class.

- again, it's not

So, it's not an event, a `Widget` instance or even a Kivy property. Well, let's throw an error about the unknown item then :)

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bt-down.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

    <CustomWidget>:  # boom
        CustButton:
            text: "Random"
            pos: root.x, 200

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, root.y

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, 400
```

You can either check if the indentation is good (i.e. if you meant to declare the `CustomWidget` rule instead of adding it as a child). If that's the case, you can define the rule only at the first level, therefore `<Rule>:` must not have any space or tab before itself.

If you wanted to add it as a child, then you are missing the declaration of the widget in the first place. You should remove the brackets (`<>`) from the `<CustomWidget>` and create a rule for it beforehand let's say above the `<CustButton@Button>:`

```
<CustomWidget>:
    # empty

<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: 'bt-down.png'
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1

    CustomWidget:
        CustButton:  # boom with AssertionError
            text: "Random"
            pos: root.x, 200

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, root.y

        CustButton:
            text: "Buttom"
            pos: 200, 400
```

The Parser doesn't like it either, because you used the rule you're declaring inside itself. Therefore you should switch the `CustButton` in this example to something that's already available to you. E.g. a `Button`.